# Why can't I extract the admob demo app from the google site?

Tags: eclipse, admob

Ok, so on this site: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addadview

I am trying to download the example admob project on the page...it downloads, but then when I extract it shows the 2 files with a 0 kb size.  Am I doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

no problem with the zip here, try download it again

Comment: This answer isn't constructive, please try to limit these suggestions and comments to the comments field of the question